# Two infinite bases for a vector space have equal cardinality

Tags: linear-algebra, solution-verification, set-theory, cardinals, hamel-basis

Let $V$ be a vector space over a field $\mathbb{K}$, such that $V$ admits an infinite linearly independent set. Let $B$ and $B'$ be two bases for $V$. Then $|B|=|B'|$.

My approach:

Let $\mathcal{F}(B)$ and $\mathcal{F}(B')$ be the collections of all finite subsets of $B$ and $B'$. The idea is to conclude that $|\mathcal{F}(B)|=|\mathcal{F}(B')|$, from which we can deduce that $|B|=|B'|$ (since $|\mathcal{F}(B)|=|B|$).

There is a theorem which says that if there is a countable-to-one function $\phi: X\to Y$ between two sets $X$ and $Y$ then $|X|\le \aleph_0 |Y|$.

To this end, suppose, without loss of generality, that $|\mathcal{F}(B)|\le \mathcal{F}(B')$. Then there is a surjective function $\phi$ from $\mathcal{F}(B')$ to $\mathcal{F}(B)$. Thus for $x\in \mathcal{F}(B)$, $\phi^{-1}(\{x\})$ exists and is countable (since $\mathcal{F}(B')$ is countable). Hence, $|\mathcal{F}(B')|\le \aleph_0 |\mathcal{F}(B)|=|\mathcal{F}(B)|$. So that $|B|=|\mathcal{F}(B)|=|\mathcal{F}(B')|=|B'|$, as required.

Please let me know whether my proof is fine. I'm not very confident in this field yet.

Comment: Why is $\mathcal{F}(B')$ countable?

Comment: Because this is the set of all finite subsets of $B'$. But a finite subset contains finitely many elements. But we can count them by their finite cardinality. Now I'm not so certain, however, if it's countable or not. Would appreciate some hints.

Comment: Yeah but being infinite can mean being a lot bigger than countable... what if $|B| = \mathbb{R}$?

Comment: My intuition was that, since all elements of $\mathcal{F}(B')$ are countable sets themselves, $\mathcal{F}(B')$ itself is countable.

Comment: I mean, suppose $B$ has size at least that of $\mathbb{R}$. Then $\mathcal{F}(B)$ contains, in particular, the singleton $\{b\}$ for every $b \in B$, so...

Comment: Good point. Would you give me a suggestion on how to revise this proof?

Answer (score 1):

First prove the following lemma.

> Let $A$ be a set, $\eta$ be a cardinal number, and $(B_a)_{a\in A}$ be a family of sets satisfying $|B_a|\le\eta$ for all $a\in A$. Then
>   $$
> \left| \cup_{a\in A}B_a \right| \le |A|\eta.
> $$

Sketch of proof in spoiler below:

> Without loss of generality, suppose $(B_a)_{a\in A}$ are pairwise disjoint. Choose an injection $g_a:B_a\to E$ for each $a\in A$, where $E$ is set of cardinality $\eta$. Define an injection from $\cup_{a\in A}B_a\to A\times E$ by mapping $x$ in the union to the element $(a,g_a(x))$ in $A\times E$, where $a\in A$ is such that $x\in B_a$. Prove this is a well-defined injection.

Now suppose $A$ and $B$ are infinite bases of a vector space. For each $a\in A$ find a finite subset $B_a$ of $B$ such that $a$ is in the span of $B_a$. Then $B=\cup_{a\in A}B_a$. Use this and the lemma to obtain $|B|\le|A|$. More details are in the spoiler below:

> We obtain $B=\cup_{a\in A}B_a$ since $B$ is linearly independent and $A$ is spanning. Using the lemma, we have $$ |B|=|\cup_{a\in A}B_a|\le|A|\aleph_0=|A|, $$ because $|B_a|<\aleph_0$ for each $a\in A$. Then repeat the same argument to get $|A|\le|B|$, and conclude using the Cantor-Schröder-Bernstein theorem.

Comment: If $A$ is uncountable, could we still say that $|B_a|\le |\mathbb{N}|$?

Comment: @sequence Yes. The reason $|B_a|\le|\mathbb{N}|$ for each $a\in A$ is because we chose $B_a$ to be finite. We can always do this because in order for $B$ to be a basis, every element in the vector space must be in the span of a finite subset of $B$.

Comment: Is it true that $\mathcal{F}(A)$ is countable even if $A$ is uncountable? @JohnGriffin

Comment: @sequence No. If $A$ is infinite, then $|\mathcal{F}(A)|=|A|$.

Comment: So if $A$ is uncountable and $B_a$ is finite, then how does this imply that $\bigcup B_a$ is countable? @JohnGriffin

Comment: @sequence It doesn't. We only know that $|\cup_{a\in A}B_a|\le|A|$.

Comment: You say that we know that $B=|\bigcup B_a|\le |\mathbb{N}|$. But how? Since if $B$ is uncountable (since $A$ is uncountable and there are uncountably many $a\in A$), its cardinality may be greater than $\aleph_0$.  @JohnGriffin

Comment: @sequence I didn't say that anywhere. We know $B=\cup_{a\in A}B_a$ because $B$ is linearly independent and $A$ is spanning. We know $|\cup_{a\in A}B_a|\le|A||\mathbb{N}|$ by the lemma and the fact that each $B_a$ is finite. Finally $A$ infinite implies $|A||\mathbb{N}|=|A|$.

Comment: By the lemma, we can say that $|\bigcup B_a|\le |A||B|$, so why $|A||\mathbb{N}$|?  @JohnGriffin

Comment: @sequence That's an unfortunate use of notation on my part. The $B$ in the lemma is not the same as the $B$ in the proof which follows. In the lemma, $B$ is a set whose cardinality is at least that of every $B_a$. In the proof, this role is filled by $\mathbb{N}$. I'll edit the answer to fix this issue.